# How can I see where a mesh is open?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a mesh that is supposedly open, but I can't see any holes in it. Is there a way I could find where they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the menu Edit > Preferences > Addons tab, search the addon 3D Print Toolbox and enable it.

Back in the viewport, <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into edit mode. In the Sidebar > 3DPrint tab, Analyze panel, hit the `Solid` button.

It should show you "non-manifold edges" in the "Results", you can click it to select the edges:

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want to bother fixing holes manually, you have the "Make Manifold" button under the Clean-Up sub-panel:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If there's a hole in your mesh, that's someplace where the [mesh is "non-manifold"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry), and you can use a [`Select Non Manifold`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/all_by_trait.html#non-manifold) operation in *Edit Mode* via menu *Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold*, in either vertex or edge select mode, to quickly select all such boundaries:

[image]

You can see on the operator panel that I've disabled all but *Boundaries*, which gives me the borders between holes and mesh.  Other aspects of being non-manifold are just as important (more important, really) than boundaries, so odds are that if you need to fix boundaries, you need to fix everything else as well-- you might consider selecting all non-manifold, regardless of subtype.  (But "extend" isn't a subtype, it just means, add whatever gets selected to any existing selection.)

Once selected, you can quickly *Zoom To* with <kbd>NumPad .</kbd> (numpad period) the selected, and/or hide all but the selected (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).